# Passing a range to Excel User Defined Function and assigning it to an array

Tags: arrays, excel, range, user-defined-functions, vba

I am trying to

1. pass two ranges - *multiple rows single column* - to a user defined function in Excel 2007,
2. then assign it to an array for processing.

Can anybody tell me how to assign such range to an array?

The range is not constant as I am using an UDF in different cells for different data so I cannot use e,g, `Range("A1:A10")`

The code is working when I just use `Data1.Rows.Cells(i, 1)` instead of arrays. But I think it is better to use one dimensional arrays for efficiency.

Here is my current code

```
Function Sample(Data1 As Range, Data2 As Range) As Double

 'Size of Data1 and Data2
 Dim rows As Integer
 rows = Data1.Rows.Count 

 'Declaring two one dimensional arrays
 Dim data1Array(rows) As Double --- Getting error here
 Dim data2Array(rows) As Double --- Getting error here

 Dim diff As Double
 Dim average As Double
 Dim i As Integer

 'Assigning Range to Array
 data1Array = Data1 --- Getting Error here
 data2Array = Data2 --- Getting Error here

 average = 0
 diff = 0

 For i = 1 To rows

   diff = data1Array(i) - data2Array(i)

   If diff < 0 Then
     diff = diff * -1
   End If

   average = diff + average

 Next i

 Sample = average/rows

End Function
```

Comment: Declare Data1Array and Data2Array as Variants (assignment of ranges to them won't work otherwise).

Comment: Thanks for correction, second error is gone. But first one is still there.
Now I can access data in Data1Array but through two dimensions like this Data1Array(i,1). Can it be like this Data1Array(i) i.e. one dimension?

Comment: First-rather don't use `rows` as variable name- that is key word in Excel VBA...

Comment: ooops sorry I just wrote it here otherwise I am using numberOfRows. Thanks

Comment: Declare you array variables this way: `Dim data1Array as Variant`. Dimension of your array will be set automatically when line `data1Array = Data1` is called.

Comment: @MrA2Z - yes. `Application.Transpose` can force a single row or single column 2D variant into 1D. See below

Comment: Thanks everybody, now it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this to work with 1D ranges which includes testing for

1. unequal ranges
2. single cell ranges (can't use variants)

**sample sub**

```
Sub Test()
MsgBox Sample([a1:a3], [a5:a7])
End Sub
```

**function**

```
 Function Sample(Data1 As Range, Data2 As Range)

 Dim X
 Dim Y
 Dim lngCnt As Long
 Dim dbDiff As Double
 Dim dbAvg As Double

 If Data1.rows.Count <> Data2.rows.Count Then
 Sample = "Different range sizes"
 Exit Function
 ElseIf Data1.rows.Count = 1 Then
 Sample = "Single cell range"
 Exit Function
 End If

 X = Application.Transpose(Data1)
 Y = Application.Transpose(Data2)

 For lngCnt = 1 To UBound(X)
   dbDiff = X(lngCnt) - Y(lngCnt)
   If dbDiff < 0 Then
     dbDiff = dbDiff * -1
   End If
   dbAvg = dbDiff + dbAvg
 Next

 Sample = dbAvg / lngCnt

End Function
```

Comment: How do I create function accepting an array of ranges?