# Passing a row range to Excel User Define Function and assign it to an array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range, user-defined-functions

I am trying to

1. pass two ranges - multiple column single row - to a user defined function in Excel 2007,
2. then assigning it to an array for processing.

   Function MAE(actualData As Range, forecastData As Range) As Double

   ```
    Dim data
    Dim forecast
    Dim error As Double
    Dim average As Double
    Dim i As Long

    data = Application.Transpose(actualData)
    forecast = Application.Transpose(forecastData)
    average = 0
    error = 0

    For i = 1 To UBound(data)

      error = data(i) - forecast(i)
      If error < 0 Then
        error = error * -1
      End If

      average = error + average

    Next i

    MAE = average / UBound(data)

    End Function
   ```

I have posted a thread earlier in this forum, here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15940047/passing-a-range-to-excel-user-defined-function-and-assigning-it-to-an-array)

In that thread I asked about passing a single column as Range to a user defined function. After your suggestions, I modified the code and it is working perfectly when I pass two single columns.

But when I pass two rows then it is not working. I am getting #Value error. Any suggestions about this?

Comment: Thanks KazJaw for editing, I put the spaces for code but it was not working.

Comment: You don't need a user-defined function to do this calculation.  For example, if `A1:A8` and `B1:B8` are the ranges that you want to compare, you can calculate the mean absolute difference by entering `=AVERAGE(ABS(B1:B8-A1:A8))` as an [array formula](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-HA102749563.aspx) in a worksheet cell (that is, by pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter instead of just Enter after typing in the formula).

Comment: Thanks a lot for saving my time, this is a good suggestion. I will use it now but still I would try to develop code for this and see why it is not working.

Answer (score 3):

THere's a problem with the way you're refering to your Variants by index.

If you review in the Locals window, you can see that the structure is a 2-dimensional array for each of `data` and `forecast`, but you are referring to them as 1-d arrays, which will cause the formula to fail.

Simply revise to:

```
error = data(i, 1) - forecast(i, 1)
```

And that should avoid the error.

Here is the Locals window, which shows the dimensions and lets you browse the arrays.

[image: Screenshot of locals window]

Comment: Thanks. Isn't Application.Transpose converting it to a single dimensional array? I get this suggestion from my other thread linked in the question. A column can be assigned to an array using Application.Transpose then how can I do the same thing for row?

Comment: Try adding another `Transpose`, like, after `forecast = Application.Transpose(forecastData)` then do: `forecast = Application.Transpose(forecast)`.  This seems to work for me to convert to a 1d array, although this doesn't seem at all intuitive (or correct) based on the documentation.